# Bug fixing on JAVA beans deployed as OSGI plugin

Tags: xpages

I deploy a Java bean together with some custom controls and css as an OSGI plugin.
So far so good.

The troubles start when there is a bug in the bean. Debugging the Java bean is no problem but bug fixing is because its not easy to overrule the bean from the plugin.

So far i found 2 methods but both are not perfect:

1) Copy the java bean into the nsf that has the error. Rename the class and also rename the calls in the custom controls. Once that is done its treated as a different class and i can debug and change.

2) Copy the java bean to nsf with the bug. Deploy a new OSGI plugin witout the Java beans.

As you can see both methods require manual intervention and once i fix the bug i have to undo all the changes and deploy everything again.

Is there a better way to develop and debug the controls within the nsf that has the problem?

Comment: I see your problem is to debug your code after some change in designer. I think local Domino installation will allow faster restarts. Or take a look at http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20SDK%20for%20Eclipse%20RCP/summary

Comment: Its not an issue of speed. I find it extremly unprofessional to just partially uninstall a feature just for bug fixing of one app.

Comment: Thanks for the link but i think even this setup wont solve the problem. The Java bean is installed on the server so i cant overrule it regardless which eclipse version i use. Am i right?

Comment: Debugging in production is unprofessional as well. I think you should install separate Domino box with above mentioned toolkit to debug your app.

Comment: I wouldnt debug in production but the issue is the same on every server. If i install the OSGI plugin and want to debug it i would have to partially deactivate it.